# Какая разница между string и String?

Tags: c#, строки

Чем отличаются `string` и `String` (обратите внимание на регистр) в C#?

```
string s = "Hello, World";

String S = "Hello, World";
```

Какие есть указания для их использования? В чем концептуальное различие?

<sub>Оригинальный вопрос: [What's the difference between String and string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string)</sub>

Answer (score 22):

В языке C# `string` — алиас `System.String`. Во время выполнения разницы между ними нет. Во время компиляции есть незначительная разница: употребление `String` без указания полного имени класса требует `using System;`.

Это лишь один из алиасов. Вот полный список:

```
object:  System.Object
string:  System.String
bool:    System.Boolean
byte:    System.Byte
sbyte:   System.SByte
short:   System.Int16
ushort:  System.UInt16
int:     System.Int32
uint:    System.UInt32
long:    System.Int64
ulong:   System.UInt64
float:   System.Single
double:  System.Double
decimal: System.Decimal
char:    System.Char
```

Кроме `string` и `object`, все алиасы соответствуют value-типам. Тип `decimal`, хоть и является value-типом, не является примитивным. Единственный примитивный тип без алиаса — `System.IntPtr`.

В спецификации все value-типы с алиасами называются простыми (simple types). Для задания константных значений простых типов могут использоваться литералы, для других value-типов литералов не существует. (В VB.NET есть литералы для `DateTime`.)

Единственный случай, когда использование алиасов обязательно — это при задании базового типа перечисления.

```
public enum Foo : UInt32 {} // Ошибка компиляции
public enum Bar : uint   {} // Компилируется
```

В случае общего для нескольких языков API рекомендуется использовать полные имена типов. Например, класс `BinaryReader` включает методы `ReadInt32` и `ReadSingle`, но не `ReadInt` или `ReadFloat`.

Следует обратить внимание, что назначение ключевых слов отличается от языка к языку. Например, в то время как `long` в C# — это `Int64`, `long` в C++ может иметь любую длину: хоть 16, хоть 32 бита (зависит от платформы). В C++/CLI `long` соответствует `Int32`. Если в вашем коде много взаимодействия между языками, то может иметь смысл использовать имена CLR во избежание путаницы.

Ещё один нюанс: если в какой-нибудь библиотеке будет объявлен тип `Foo.String`, то использование `String` может привести к конфликтам, а использование `string` всегда будет однозначно. Однако этот случай скорее невероятен, потому что объявление подобного типа запрещается Framework Design Guidelines и здравой логикой.

Ранее [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) (и встроенный в Visual Studio анализ) рекомендовал использовать `string` для переменных и `String` для вызовов методов (например, `String.Format()`). В последних версиях рекомендация была изменена: рекомендуется всегда использовать алиас `string`, в том числе при вызове методов (`string.Format()`).

<sub>Перевод-компиляция ответов к оригинальному вопросу [What's the difference between String and string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

`string` - это псевдоним для `System.String`, технически говоря, нет никаких различий. Эта ситуация аналогична соответствию `int`/`System.Int32`.

Согласно стилевым директивам, `string` следует использовать при указании ссылки на объект

```
string place = "world";
```

Соответственно, общепринято использовать `String` в случае указания на класс

```
string greet = String.Format("Hello {0}!", place);
```

Такой стиль предлагается Microsoft их собственных [примерах](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Format.aspx#Format1_Example)

<sub>Оригинальный ответ: [What's the difference between String and string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string/7077#7077)</sub>

Comment: 1. Если переводите, то переводите полностью. Информация в оригинальном ответе устарела, в оригинальном ответе об этом есть отметка, а вы её почему-то пропустили. 2. Пропущенный предлог ваш перевод не красит — уж при переводе четырёх предложений можно было проверить грамотность. 3. Ну и бардак с отсутствием ссылок на оригиналы надо прекращать...

Answer (score 3):

Никакой принципиальной разницы между ними нет *(разумеется, кроме регистра первого символа в названии)*.
Тип `string` является синонимом типа `System.String`.
Соответственно, для использования второго варианта, вам нужно либо каждый раз писать полное имя типа `System.String`, либо иметь `using System;` в коде.

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к другим ответам:

`String` — просто имя типа, так что вы можете создать свой тип с именем `String`. А `string` — ключевое слово, создать свой тип с именем `string` не получится.